# Golang var should have comment or should be unexported

Tags: go

I am facing this error in my Go code
exported var should have a comment or be unexported 
error message

> install.go:44:2: exported var URLSuffix should have comment or be unexported

Comment: Its not actually error!

Comment: Please go through `GoLang specs` first. Also, read docs to save your time.

Comment: That's not an error. It's a lint warning. And it should be pretty self-explanatory. What part do you need help understanding?

Answer (score 6):

`URLSuffix` start with an uppercase letter, so it is exported, so add a comment right before it, as described in the [Code Review guide](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#doc-comments), and [effective Go commentary](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#commentary):

```
// URLSuffix is ... (complete here)
URLSuffix aType
```

This is a *warning* from [`golang/lint`](https://github.com/golang/lint), illustrated in [`golang/lint` issue 191](https://github.com/golang/lint/issues/191).